# Python Special Chars Escape

Tags: python, regex

how would I get this into a string in python? I know I need to escape special chars but I don't know how. I tried adding backslashes but it didn't seem to work. I' not sure what to do.

Here is the code:

```
</th><td class='tracking'>
```

Comment: The various options are shown, with examples, in the Python tutorial: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use double quotations:

```
s = "</th><td class='tracking'>"
```

This allows you to create a string which includes single quotations.

Single quotations work as well when you use backslashes for escaping:

```
s = '</th><td class=\'tracking\'>'
```

Answer (score 3):

I would just use triple-quotes like below, there's other ways but triple-quotes are pretty fool-proof in Python:

```
"""</th><td class='tracking'>"""
```